# Fixing Dewalt power drill runout

Tags: powertools

I've got a well-made old cordless drill, it works well but has too much runout (a long straight bit wobbles side to side too much). What part(s) would likely need to be replaced to fix the bad bearing that causes runout? Motor? Transmission? Chuck? Or is it unfixable?

I need a drill with a 43 mm collar, hard to find, my old one has that size collar. Drill is a DeWalt DC987, if that matters.

Comment: You have made sure that it is the drill and not the drill bit by testing?

Comment: Is it the chuck or chuck bearings?

Comment: yes, I tried the drill bit in my other drill, no runout.

Comment: There are only a couple bearings in those things. Open it up and have a look. Could be a deformed case and not a bearing. Could also be a bent chuck shaft.

Comment: I'm also miserly with my O.G. DeWalt tools, but this year I bit the bullet and replaced them with modern brushless versions during a good sale. Trust me--it's worth doing if you're able. Power, battery life, electronic clutch. All big wins.

Comment: I've got a small collection of the older 18v DeWalts out in my shed. They're bulkier than the newer 20v tools, but run just fine. Sadly, battery prices are _still_ insane. I'm loathe to get rid of them, though, and will probably pass them on to my youngest (with a 20v battery adapter) when he finally moves out.

Comment: Back on topic... I'd suggest that you go look for parts availability. You might have difficulty finding parts for the older 18v tools and find that new tools are your only option.

Comment: I ran into this problem with one of the older dewalt drills. @FreeMan is right, you will probably have a tough time finding parts for it, and if you do the price will probably be so outrageous that you'll be better off buying a new one. keep the old one for... more primitive drilling operations (like attaching a grinding disc or a table saw blade).  isherwood is also right, the newer brushless designs are amazing.

Comment: @FreeMan no-name batteries for dewalt XRP on ebay with 2 Amp-hours are $19 shipped, work great! Also, you're correct most parts not available, but the chuck is, thats most likely what I need.

Comment: I've wondered about the aftermarket batteries, but considering how much lighter the new batteries (and tools) are, it makes investing (even if it's only a $20) in one a more difficult proposition. (Lack of) parts availability is the most likely cause of upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on **why** it has runout.

Often debris jammed (or internal damage) inside the chuck. That can be as "simple" (often not so simple) as disassembling, cleaning out the debris, (and/or filing/grinding away the offending defect,) then reassembling; depending on what's going on.

That is: "not bearing runout" which tends to be pretty hard to spot unless it's extreme. It's also your most likely to be "reasonable" repair effort.

Otherwise, you have only a couple of actual bearings. It's hardly ever cost-effective to replace the bearings rather than the whole tool, in part because they can be difficult to find, or the part of the case they mount to may be damaged, rather than the bearing itself, or the worn bearing may have caused damage to the motor by letting parts slop around and hit/scrape each other.

Comment: I checked the chuck, no visible damage, looks surprisingly good inside there.